# Keeping client-side libraries and npm packages in sync

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, client-side, server-side

I'm trying to keep my client side and server side testing libraries in sync (specifically mocha, chai, sinon, and coffee-script).

Right now I'm thinking the only solution may be to use symbolic links to the files under node_modules. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Abhik

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing the client-side code into Node.js modules you can also create client-side code from Node.js modules by using something like Browserify. Those Node.js modules have to be optimized for the browser though.